# Allow html tag in a pure CSS tooltip

Tags: html, css

I have this pure CSS tooltip.

```
<span data-tooltip="The security code is a 3-digit number<br />on the back of your Visa or Mastercard debit or credit card, or a 4-digit number on the front of your American Express card.">Help</span>
```

Can can I allow html like `<br />` in it ?

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.23809524em;
  height: 1.23809524em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #252525;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltip .tooltip__anchor {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 6px;
}
.tooltip .tooltip__text {
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  padding: 0.61904762em;
  left: 1.48571429em;
  top: -0.92857143em;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  line-height: 20px;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltip__text {
  opacity: 1;
}
.tooltip:last-child {
  margin-left: 0.92857143em;
}
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
[data-tooltip]:after {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #252525;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  padding: 2px 12px;
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
[data-tooltip]:not(:hover):after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<br /><br /><br />
<span data-tooltip="The security code is a 3-digit number<br />on the back of your Visa or Mastercard debit or credit card, or a 4-digit number on the front of your American Express card.">Help</span>
<br /><br /><br />
```

Thanks.

---

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/buhdkmpj/

Comment: you cannot, you can eventually do the carriage return in the code and use `white-space:pre;` https://jsfiddle.net/buhdkmpj/1/

Comment: `<br>` does not need or use a closing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting relevant part of chapter *[12.2 The 'content' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#x18)* of *CSS 2.1 Specification* (emphasis mine):

> attr(X)
>   This function returns **as a string** the value of attribute X for the subject of the selector.

Therefore HTML tags inside attribute values will be treated as strings, rather than being parsed.

---

However you can still get line feed character to display inside your tooltip. Just change `white-space: nowrap` of `[data-tooltip]:after` to `white-space: pre` and put line feed character in place of `<br />` in your `data-tooltip` attribute.

[**Analogic demo JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7s29dj0r/).

Comment: `<br>` does not need or use a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob: Firstly, it is present in OP's question, which I only quoted. What's more, with closing tag it's also a valid XML (polyglot markup), and as such you may serve webpage as `application/xhtml+xml` with proper, elegant, vanilla XML parsing, should you desire to. Note too, that space in front of `/` is unnecessary — it was *de facto* introduced by Microsoft.

Comment: This is HTML, not XML or XHTML. The closing slash is unspecified for `<br>` or any HTML element, not used, means nothing and browsers are instructed by the spec to ignore it, making it useless and pointless.

Comment: @Rob: HTML specification does not require trailing slash indeed, but using it makes you conformant to XML rules, which in turn allows you to use polyglot markup. All web developers should always fully conform to all standards, and serving webpages with aforementioned MIME-type will allow some rules to be enforced upon you. In other words: with this slash, it may be both HTML and XHTML (XHTML5 does not really exist, but it's equivalent to serving HTML5 with right MIME-type).

Comment: There is no need or reason to conform to XML rules in HTML. The MIME-type will never be used in any HTML web site for any reason.

Comment: @Rob: There are still people, i.a. me, who prefer to write HTML5 like XHTML1.1, including the way it should always be served. Whether you want to conform to these rules is up to you, but I'm very vanilla about standards and I personally don't like how lax specification is when it comes to allowing incompliance. With that MIME-type you will immediately see all grammatical errors, hence not allowing them to stack up. Plus this slash may not help, but it doesn't hurt either, that's why version with slash is still more frequent than the one wihtout.

Comment: As I said, the HTML specification clearly states the slash does nothing, means nothing and browsers are instructed to ignore it. Using the slash in HTML gains you nothing, provides no additional information or error checking. It takes up space and bandwidth. It's pointless and useless.

Comment: @Rob: As I said, the HTML specification clearly states that you may write in an XML-conformant way, allowing you to serve webpages with `application/xhtml+xml` MIME-type, which in turn provides, using your words — error checking.

Comment: And if you are serving your page as application/xhtml+xml, then you are serving XML/XHTML, not HTML, which is a different animal and does not apply to HTML or anything I said.

Comment: @Rob: XHTML5 does not *de jure* exist, whatsoever. XHTML5 is simply HTML written with XML-syntax and served with the said MIME-type. So it's all still about the very same HTML.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html

You can include `&#13;` instead for Carriage Return.
Hope this helps you.